# Body watermark is not removed when asking new question

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

With the iOS app v1.2.0.140 the watermark in the body section when creating a new question is not removed after content is entered. If I cancel the creation and then resume the draft everything is fine.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by a recent refactoring to our UITextView subclass which allows displaying placeholder text. A method was being overridden, but never calling the implementation of its super.

Should  be fixed in **beta version 1.2.0.141**.